# Fluid simulation flows out of the shell

Tags: baking

I'm simulating the fluid in a pipe as shown in the image below
[image]

I have set the inflow to -z axis and made the pipe a obstacle and also the volume initialization as shell.But still it flows outside of the pipe.
[image]

Can some one help me resolving this issue.

ive also added the quad view with properties of inflow and domain

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your settings as screen capture for the inflow.  Use more readable view in your screen capture .  In particular show your pipe thickness as a close up.  Quadview is available.

Comment: Show the later stages of the fluid simulation as well.  You can compose your images with free GIMP if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some options. See which may apply to your situations.

- I am not sure I agree with the -z setting for inflow as you currently wrote. 0 or +y seems more appropriate.  Fluid will flow with gravity.
- Make your pipe thicker or surround the spout with an outflow.
- If the fluid is only visible coming out of the pipe use a smaller pipe spout with more thickness.  One pipe for obstacle and no render. Another distinct pipe for render and not a fluid component.  This may preserve more resolution.
- Make your pipe thicker while preserving internal wall.
  See Fatten Shrink on the Blender Menus in edit mode.

Comment: I've updated the quad view with properties